# Как сделать контроллер недоступным на время?

Tags: node.js, express

У меня есть контроллер который при поступлении запроса делает очень долгую операцию. И мне надо его заблокировать на это время(выдавать ошибку при обращении на него). Должно получится что-то вроде этого.

```
app.get(
//1) Поступил первый запрос 
//2) Длинная I/O операция 
//3) Поступил второй запрос выбрасваем ошибку(обработчик недоступен) 
//4)Длинная I/O операция закончилась 
//5) Мы снова можем принимать запросы
)
```

С помощью чего такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

```
let hardLoadingOpFlag;

app.get('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
  if (hardLoadingOpFlag === true) {
    return res.status(429);
  }

  hardLoadingOpFlag = true;
  
  hardLoadingOp()
    .finally(() => {
      hardLoadingOpFlag = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]